# WPF MVVM How to create Treeview with dynamic / nested data using Caliburn Micro

Tags: wpf, xaml, nested, treeview, caliburn.micro

I have a simple model like following:

```
    public class TreeItem : PropertyChangedBase
    {
        private string name;
        public string Name
        {
            get => name;
            set
            {
                name = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Name);
            }
        }

        public ObservableCollection<TreeItem> Children { get; } = new ObservableCollection<TreeItem>();
    }
```

The viewmodel:

```
    public ShellViewModel()
    {
        var data = server.GetData();
        BuildTree(data);
    }

    public ObservableCollection<TreeItem> Root { get; } = new ObservableCollection<TreeItem>();

    private void BuildTreeFromObject( AnObjectType data )
    {
        // it's ok here. I build the tree here
    }
```

Yes, it has nested collection.
I get the data from server and it has also nested list. I can't know how many level of list the data from server has. In ViewModel I can build the tree to assign the property Root. But I am not sure how to write the treeview in XAML.

```
<TreeView
    x:Name="TreeView"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Root}">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate
            DataType="{x:Type models:TreeItem}"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Children}">
            <TextBlock Style="{DynamicResource TextBlockStyle}" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate
                    DataType="{x:Type models:TreeItem}"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Children}">
                    <TextBlock Style="{DynamicResource TextBlockStyle}" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                        <HierarchicalDataTemplate
                            DataType="{x:Type models:TreeItem}"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Children}">
                            <TextBlock Style="{DynamicResource TextBlockStyle}" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                                <HierarchicalDataTemplate
                                    DataType="{x:Type models:TreeItem}"
                                    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Children}">
                                    <TextBlock Style="{DynamicResource TextBlockStyle}" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type models:TreeItem}">
                                            <TextBlock Style="{DynamicResource TextBlockStyle}" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                            </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

As you see my treeview can handle only the depth level 4. If the data from server has more than 4 levels I need to change it :( 
Can anyone show me how to create dynamic treeview's content using such nested model? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need all those levels.
I think just one hierarchicaldatatemplate should work.

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate
    DataType="{x:Type models:TreeItem}"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Children}">
    <TextBlock Style="{DynamicResource TextBlockStyle}" Text="{Binding Path=Name
```

}">

The leaf items are just a TreeItem with no children

What that template is saying is whenever you get an object of type treeitem then use this template. Give me a headed itemscontrol with a header of Name and then show the children in the itemspanel.
When it gets the children of a treeitem, they turn out to be treeitem so it templates that into the same again.. and so on.